# How GENERATED_GBL_DATA_SIZE value caliculated

Tags: u-boot

While checking the u-boot source, I saw the following code snippet to caliculate GENERATED_GBL_DATA_SIZE value in lib/asm-offsets.c.

```
(sizeof(struct global_data)+15) & ~15)
```

Can you tell me why we are adding 15 and doing bitwise-AND operation with ~15. I am referring "2014.07" U-boot source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This rounds up the size to the next multiple of 16 (2^4). bytes. I don't know why its done.

Comment: Thanks, may be for alignment purpose it was done.